# List all subscripts in an expression

Tags: replacement, rule, subscript

Say we have the following expression:

$r_{1,3} r_{1,2}^3 m^2-r_{1}r_{4,2,1}$

(Sorry I had to use TeX, read as Mathematica input notation)

I need a function that lists all the subscripts of $r$.

The result should be: `{{1,3},{1,2},{1},{4,2,1}}`

`InputForm` for the input expression:

```
expr = ToExpression["r_{1,3} r_{1,2}^3 m^2-r_{1}r_{4,2,1}", TeXForm];
InputForm @ expr
```

> m^2*Subscript[r, 1, 2]^3*Subscript[r, 1, 3] - Subscript[r, 1]*Subscript[r, 4, 2, 1]

Comment: Can't properly write subscripts here. Had to use tex. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = ToExpression["r_{1,3} r_{1,2}^3 m^2-r_{1}r_{4,2,1}", TeXForm];
Cases[expr, Subscript[_, s__] :> {s}, {0, Infinity}]
```

> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1}, {4, 2, 1}}

```
Cases[ToExpression["r_{1,2}", TeXForm], Subscript[_, s__] :> {s}, {0, Infinity}]
```

> {{1, 2}}

Comment: Close enough! Fails when expr has only one term, e.g. r_{1,2}

Comment: @Ivan, adding level `0` to the last argument fixes that issue.